# Cpp Variable/Structure to store 128-bit data

Tags: c++

I need some variable/struct to store 32hex number or 128-bit number in an STL container. Do you have any suggestion for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot perform arithmetic on 128 bit data without some big integer library (or non-standard SSE extensions I don't know much about anyway).
If you just need to store it use a `std::pair<uint64_t, uint64_t>` or a struct:

```
struct bit128
{
    uint64_t higher, lower;
}
```

If you need bitwise operations use `std::bit_vector`.
If you need arithmetic you have to use a big integer library like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: First sentence isn't technically correct. It depends on the platform, and you don't need a library - you can do it yourself.

Comment: @Pubby: you can do everything yourself.

Comment: the OP never said he *wasn't* using x64, in which case 128bit arithmetic is possible use the RDX:RAX spanned register. so maybe you first sentence should reflect that its for 32bit systems only

Comment: I am using 32-bit machine. I don't want to do 128bit math, I just need to store these numbers in an STL container then perform 128-bit lookup.

Comment: @ARH: to perform 128-bit lookup, you can just use the pair and STL will perform lexicographical ordering.